# Check if RunOnUiThread is necessary?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm stuck in a little problem:
I have written a communication class that fires `OnResponseData` when data arrives.
Now i need to check if the caller is the Activity itself or the class.

See this code:

```
private void OnResponseData(ushort ID, byte function, byte[] values)
{
#if (winm || win7) // windows mobile or phone 7
    if (this.m_Container.Form.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.m_Container.Form.BeginInvoke(new ModbusTCP.Master.ResponseData(OnResponseData), new object[] { id, function, values });
            return;
        }
#else
    if (??) // well this is the problem, what i need to check here?
    { 
        Action newAc;
        newAc = delegate { OnResponseData(ID, function, values); };
        this.m_Container.Form.RunOnUiThread(newAc);
        return;
    }
#endif
...
```

`this.m_Container.Form` is my `Activity`
I basically need InvokeRequired for Android.

Thanks so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Android.OS.Looper](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.OS.Looper) instances. [Android.OS.Looper.MyLooper()](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.OS.Looper.MyLooper) returns the `Looper` associated with the current thread; if there is no `Looper`, then `null` is returned. Meanwhile, [Looper.MainLooper](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.OS.Looper.MainLooper) (and also [Context.MainLooper](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Context.MainLooper)) is the `Looper` for the UI thread. Thus:

```
if (Looper.MyLooper() != Looper.MainLooper)
{ 
    Action newAc;
    newAc = delegate { OnResponseData(ID, function, values); };
    this.m_Container.Form.RunOnUiThread(newAc);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ( this.m_Container instanceOf Activity )
```

does this solve the problem !

Comment: since instanceOf is not defined in c# I tryed is instead. But theres no effect. someone got another idea?

Comment: The C# equivalent to Java's `instanceof` keyword is the `is` keyword: `if (this.m_Container is Activity) ...`